# Passing Multiple Provider/Broker URL Spring JMS ndi template

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

We are using Spring JMS integration for connecting our application to Tibco EMS product.  Our jndi template is defined as follows bean:

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${app.java.naming.factory.initial}</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${app.java.naming.provider.url}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Value of app.java.naming.provider.url is defined in property file as of now as :

```
app.java.naming.provider.url=tcp://server1:7222
```

I want to make our application pass multiple provider urls is it possible as follows:

```
app.java.naming.provider.url=tcp://server1:7222,tcp://server2:7222,tcp://server3:7222,tcp://server4:7222
```

At given time only one server will up, but if other goes down we dont want to change config and re-deploy hence above mechanism.

How Spring JNDI template works with multiple provider urls.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? We would like to do the same thing.

Comment: we tried but it was always tries to connect to first urls and if not available it fails